# Show interstitial Ad after download completed dialogue box pop up

Tags: android, webview, admob, interstitial

i want to show interstitial ad when someone download my app's image in webView , now when user download the image pop up shows that image downloaded completely with ok , i want to show interstitial Ad when user click on that ok button , this is my pop up code

```
registerReceiver(downloadListener, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));

BroadcastReceiver downloadListener = new BroadcastReceiver(){
public void onReceive(Context ct, Intent intent){
    new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
          .title("Download Completed")
          .content("Download Successfully Completed")
          .positiveText("OK")
          .show();
}
```

thanks

Comment: did you register and send broad cast on ok button click??

Comment: no how to do ? @HemantParmar

Comment: i post the ans, have look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First implement the positive button click listener like this and then you can write your code for ad in that listener

```
new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
.onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(MaterialDialog dialog, DialogAction which) {
        // here you can write the code for showing ads
    }
})
```

Comment: Post some more code and I will help you. If possible class code

Answer (score 0):

Register local broadcast receiver where you want callback, have look

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
          LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(downloadListener, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));

    }
```

now on ok button broadcast receiver

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setAction(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Hope it will help you!!